# jQuery show - "push" contents at speed of animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

When using show with an animation, if any of the elements contained within the element I show have dimensions - the dom seems to spring out to make room for the fully expanded element before animating the display.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2K848/9/

```
<div id="container" style="border: thin solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <div style="display: none; border: thin solid red;" id="expander">
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: thin solid blue;">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="expander_button" value="test">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expander_button").click(function(){
        if($("#expander").is(':visible')){
            $("#expander").hide();
        }
        else{
            $("#expander").show('scale', { percent: 100, origin: [ 'top', 'right' ] }, 1500);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to make the scaling "around" the element happen at the speed of the animation? So in the jsfiddle above, the test button would be "pushed" away slowly instead of springing away to make room for the entire animation, similar to how slideToggle does it's thing.

Comment: You should probably look into the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Boaz suggested, this requires using `.animate()` as opposed to `.show`...

```
$("#expander").animate({height:'show',width:'show'}, 1500);
```

...along with some CSS tweaks to ensure your elements are positioned and scale as desired. Specifically, adding a `float:right` to your `#expander` DIV as well as adding a clear-fix DIV below it, before the button to ensure the button moves down smoothly as the DIV expands.

Working jsFiddle, forked from yours, here: http://jsfiddle.net/vkf9j/